# Excel Data to gridview ? In Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application, i am trying to get the data from excel and bind to gridview, it is working  fine, but when the excel contain the row whcih is having only single value in the cell and remaing cells are empty then it is showing default letters like [F, G, H..] like in top of the gridview header.The below is the actual excel Sheet 
[image]

below  is the excel sheet format 
[image]

This is my code which is in page load even

```
      System.Data.DataTable dt = null;

            string excelFile = Server.MapPath("./performances.xls");
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            // Connection String. 
            String connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + excelFile + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
            // Create connection. 
            oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            // Opens connection with the database. 
            oledbConn.Open();
            // Get the data table containing the schema guid, and also sheet names. 
            dt = oledbConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            if (dt == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
            int i = 0;
            // Add the sheet name to the string array. 
            // And respective data will be put into dataset table 
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                excelSheets[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + excelSheets[i] + "]", oledbConn);
                OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                oleda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                oleda.Fill(ds, "TABLE");
                i++;
            }
            // Bind the data to the GridView 
            grdMygrd .DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            grdMygrd.DataBind();
            Session["Table"] = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: please help me, to solve this problem

Comment: could you paste some code, as it is a bit hard to understand what methods you use, to make the binding. are you binding it as a data set?

Comment: ya sure lgarioshka, i will place the code

Answer (score 0):

I have repeated your error, and it looks to me that it's a problem with the excel format. the headers in the excel document are simple merged cells, the OleDB data provider sees those cells as separate empty values, and the headers that consist of merged cells, have their values in the bottom cells. the possible solution would be to try and flatten the headers in excel, and manually paint them on your page.

it would figure, because the OleDB data provider sees the excel file as a database, and those do not actually have sub-headers.